# Entity Framework 6.1.3 navigation property only has value after query to related table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET 5 (dnx46) RC1 
I have a User class that inherits from the IdentityUser class of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity (v2.2.1):

In my DbContext, I have the relation defined OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
            .WithRequired(ur => ur.User)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
[Table("Users")]
public class User : BaseUser, IBaseUser
{
// Entity Framework Constructor
private User()
{

}

public User(string userName)
    :base(userName)
{

}
[Key]
public override int Id { get; set; }

public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;

public new virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; } = new List<UserRole>();
}
```

And a Role class:

```
[Table("Roles")]
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>, IBaseEntity, ISecureEntity
{
    // Entity Framework Constructor
    private Role()
    {

    }
    public Role(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public new string Name { get; set; }

    public new virtual ICollection<UserRole> Users { get; set; }
     public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

And a UserRole class for the join table:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>, IBaseEntity
 {
 // Entity Framework Constructor
 private UserRole()
 {

 }

 public UserRole(int userId, int roleId)
 {
     UserId = userId;
     RoleId = roleId;
 }
 public new int UserId { get; set; }
 public new int RoleId { get; set; }

 public User User { get; set; }
 public Role Role { get; set; }
```

To be sure, I've also explicitly enabled LazyLoading in my DbContext Ctor:
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;

I Have to do this hack:

```
// HACK: Check if Roles is empty on user too when updating to EF7, else remove these lines
// Lazy loading hack to get the Roles list for currentUser, seems just querying the UsersRoles table fills the roles
var user2 = currentUser;
var userRoles = await _userRoleRepository.GetAsync(r => r.UserId == user2.Id);
/* END HACK */
```

Then the currentUser.Roles navigation property suddenly has all the roles. So it seems that a query to the UsersRoles table somehow fills in the navigation property of an instance of the User class??

Can anyone explain why it works when I do the query to the table? What does it do extra?
And more importantly, how can I get the navigation property working without that unneccessary statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one bit me a while ago and took a long time to track it down.

Don't use private constructors. Make them protected.

EF wants to create proxy objects that extends your model and sets up the navigation properties. If your default constructor is private, it won't create a proxy, it'll just create a model.

Another way around this, but I don't recommend, is to use the Include statement on all your queries. If you say context.Users.Include(x=>x.UserRoles) it will work. However, the navigation properties stop at the level of your includes. This can be a nightmare to try to keep this up and you'll constantly be editing your query as you need additional navigation properties. One nice thing about this approach is you keep your private constructors and you don't have proxy objects which can cause some headaches in other areas.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is indeed the solution. I'm going to make all of my empty ctor's protected :)